# How to print a certain number of values on one line in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, primes

Hi I'm attempting to print out all the prime numbers from 1 to 4000, but I can't seem to figure out how to print 8 values and then create a new line. Im almost there but for some reason I keep printing 8 of the same value, but it does indeed print 8 numbers then skip to the next line.

Where am I going wrong to have it print the same number 8 times?

The main logic I think the problem lies is in the `isPrime()` function. If anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it.

```
bool isPrime(int number);
bool isPerfect(int number);

int main()
{

  // Print Prime Numbers
  cout << "PRIME NUMBERS: " << endl;

  int numberOfPrimes = 0, numberOfPerfects = 0;

  for (int i = 2; i < 4000; i++)
  {

      if(isPrime(i))
      {
          numberOfPrimes++;
      }
  }

  cout << endl << endl;

  cout << "PERFECT NUMBERS: " << endl;

  for (int j = 1; j <= 4000; j++)
  {
      if(isPerfect(j))
      {
          numberOfPerfects++;
      }
  }

  cout << endl << endl;
  cout << "The total number of primes form 1 to 4000 is " << numberOfPrimes << endl << endl;
  cout << "The total number of perfects from 1 to 4000 is " << numberOfPerfects << endl << endl;

}

bool isPrime(int number) {

    bool numberIsPrime = true;

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            numberIsPrime = false;
            return numberIsPrime;
            break;
        }

    }


     if (numberIsPrime) 
    {  
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            count++;
            cout<< setw(6) << number << " ";

            if (count % 7 == 0)
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }



    return numberIsPrime;

}

bool isPerfect(int number)
{
    int i = 1, sum = 0;
    bool numberIsPerfect = false;

    while( i < number)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (sum == number)
    {
        numberIsPerfect = true;
        cout << setw(6) << number << " ";
    }

    return numberIsPerfect;

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PRIME NUMBERS: 
 2      2      2      2      2      2      2 
 2      3      3      3      3      3      3      3 
 3      5      5      5      5      5      5      5 
 5      7      7      7      7      7      7      7 
 7     11     11     11     11     11     11     11 
11     13     13     13     13     13     13     13 
13     17     17     17     17     17     17     17 
17     19     19     19     19     19     19     19 
19     23     23     23     23     23     23     23 
23     29     29     29     29     29     29     29 
29     31     31     31     31     31     31     31 
31     37     37     37     37     37     37     37 
37     41     41     41     41     41     41     41 
41     43     43     43     43     43     43     43 
43     47     47     47     47     47     47     47 
47     53     53     53     53     53     53     53 
53     59     59     59     59     59     59     59 
59     61     61     61     61     61     61     61 
61     67     67     67     67     67     67     67 
67     71     71     71     71     71     71     71 
71     73     73     73     73     73     73     73 
73     79     79     79     79     79     79     79 
79     83     83     83     83     83     83     83 
83     89     89     89     89     89     89     89 
89     97     97     97     97     97     97     97
```

It goes on to complete the proper primes but repeated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong to have it print the same number 8 times?

In the following `for`; you print 8 time the same prime `number`

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
    {
        count++;
        cout<< setw(6) << number << " ";
```

I think it's a work for a static variable

```
bool isPrime (int number)
 {
   static int count { 0 };

   for ( int i { 2 } ; i * i <= number ; ++i )
      if ( number % i == 0 )
         return false;

   cout << setw(6) << number << " ";

   if ( ++count == 8 )
    {
      cout << endl;

      count = 0;
    }

   return true;
 }
```

or (IMHO a little better)

```
bool isPrime (int number)
 {
   static int count { 0 };

   bool isP { true };

   if ( number == 2 ) // 2 is prime !
      ;
   else if ( 0 == (number & 1) ) // is divisible by 2 ?
      isP = false;
   else
    {
      int sq = std::sqrt(number); // calculare square root only one time

      // try dividing by odd number only
      for ( int i { 3 } ; i <= sq ; i += 2 ) 
         if ( number % i == 0 )
            isP = false;
    }

   if ( isP )
    {
      std::cout << setw(6) << number << " ";

      if ( 0 == (++count & 7) ) // is divisible by 8 ?
         std::cout << std::endl;
    }

   return isP;
 }
```

Comment: Ah didn't even think to use a static variable. Thanks for pointing that out! Is there any way to do this without the use of a static variable?

Comment: @JustinCabral - yes, you can define a counter in `main()` and pass it to `isPrime()` as parameter; en passant, I've improved my anser with another example of `isPrime()`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is poorly structured. It's not the job of `isPrime()` to print anything. `isPrime()` should return true if the argument is a prime, *and do nothing else.* Then *in the calling code,* you should print the number if prime, count the number of primes you've printed so far in the line, and break the line and zero the count when it gets to 8 or however many you want per line.

As a matter of fact, even *having* an `isPrime()` method is poor practice. It is orders of magnitude more efficient to generate all the primes in the range in a single pass over the range, via the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and *then* print them, rather than interrogate each number in the range sequentially for primeness.